# C - Pointer offset unexpected

Tags: c, pointers

I have a pointer to an array and I'm wanting to use functions like memcpy with a specific offset, however when offsetting the pointer address I'm getting a value that is more than the offset and I don't understand why. Can someone explain what is going on here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t *source[5];

    // Initial
    printf("%p\n", (void *)source); // 786796896

    // Offset by 2
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(source + 2)); // 786796912 (unexpected, more than 2)
}
```

Comment: My compiler (with default settings) gives 7 warnings. Not bad for a 20 line program.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Well if 11 is not bad, how good is 0?

Comment: `%d` is not the correct way to print a pointer. Try `%p`.

Comment: `uint8_t *ptr = source;` is a bug, as your compiler will tell you. @user16217248 has an explanation of the values you see, but this is probably undefined behaviour that just happens to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the warnings, I was using an online compiler when I made the example and didn't see them. I fixed the warnings, simplified the example and updated printf to use %p for pointers per @pmacfarlane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is when you add `2` to `source`, the array decays into a pointer type `uint8_t **`. When you perform arithmetic on a pointer, the offset added is the number of **elements** added and not the number of **bytes** if the size of the pointer element is bigger than a byte. The offset in bytes from `source + 2` is actually `2*sizeof(*source)` bytes, which is 16.

To bypass this behavior, cast `source` to a `char *`, perform the addition, then cast back. Be warned however, that doing that incorrectly can result in an unaligned access which can be bad news.

Comment: It's also UB to create the unaligned pointer

Comment: @M.M So unaligned pointers are trap-representations?

Comment: Not exactly. Converting a pointer to another pointer type with incorrect alignment is UB ; and converting integer to pointer with incorrect alignment is implemenetation-defined and may produce a trap representation.  (No idea why the inconsistency between these rules, probably historical reasons)

Comment: @M.M Well what if I convert a pointer to an integer first then convert to another pointer? Easy UB circumvention?

Comment: How would that make the pointer aligned afterwards?

Comment: @Gerhardh It wouldn't. But at least it would not be instant UB.

Comment: It's exactly the same. Creating an unaligned pointer in one way or the other yields the same result. As soon as you assign the incorrect value to the pointer you are no better than the other way before. You only added an extra step without benefit in between.

Comment: Well the trap representation would "trigger" on storing the result of the second cast , if it was in fact a trap representation . But the implementation could define unaligned values to not be trap representations.

Comment: Hmmm... there's no decayment here... the object is very different, it's an array of five pointers, and not a pointer to an array of five `int8_t`.  So please, don't confound the PO with a wrong answer.

Comment: Decayment to pointer only happens on parameter variables declared as arrays, and only at the first level, so a **parameter definition** like `double matrix[3][5]` decays into `double (*matrix)[5]`, AND NOT INTO `double ***matrix` or whatever idea you have about decayment.

Comment: in this case, the question's declared object is not a pointer, but an array of pointers, and no decayment is done, as it is a local variable, and never a function parameter.  There are five pointers to `int8_t` in the variable, uninitialized, but never a single pointer to array.  Are we crazy?  there's a full chapter (or even more) treating the somewhat obscure syntax of type definition expressions in K&R.  Please, read it.

Comment: @LuisColorado What I meant is when you add `x` to an array `a`, it's equivalent to getting the address of the element at `a[x]` the same way it would be if the array was just a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @user16217248, when you use an array name (raw, no subindex operator used) as part of an expression, that means a pointer reference to the first element of the array, You cannot refer to an array in C, but only to use the `sizeof` operator to calculate it's size.  So what you meant is the pointer to the first element, added by two, which menas pointing to two `uint8_t` positions ahead of `array`. This is just pointer arithmetic, not decayment.  Worse is when you say something like `2 + array`, which means exactly the same, and makes the expression `array[2]` equivalent to `2[array]`.  Obscure!

Comment: `array` by itself in an expression is an rvalue of type `uint8_t *`, which is different than the array type (this is `uint8_t*[5]`, as it appears in the question, or as `uint8_t(*)[5]`, as the suggested declaration should have been to have a pointer to an array)  This changes the actual type of the expression `array`'s type and makes the value passed to `printf()` to differ.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer Arthimetics need to be avoided as much as you can. For above

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t* source[5]; // array of 5 pointers of uint8_t* type

    printf("%p\n", &source[2]); // address of 3rd element place in array source
}
```

A very important point to note is it, adding 2 into source address not results in incrementing address by +2 but by +10 cause 2 was interpreted as char* [5] not char *.

```
// using without casting
char * arr[5];
char * parr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    
printf("%p\t%p\n", arr, parr);
printf("%p\t%p\n", arr+2, parr+2);

0x7ffde2925fb0  0x55b519f252a0
 +10             +2
0x7ffde2925fc0  0x55b519f252a2
```

```
//using with casting

char * arr[5];
char * parr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    
printf("%p\t%p\n", arr, parr);
printf("%p\t%p\n", (void*)arr+2, parr+2);

0x7ffde2925fb0  0x55b519f252a0
 +2               +2
0x7ffde2925fb2  0x55b519f252a2
```

Comment: Then what is the proper way to use source[2] in the context of memcpy ?

Comment: what is the use case? Also source is a array of pointers, you first need to allocate memory to elements you are about to use.

Comment: I see no advantage to going out of your way to avoid pointer arithmetic.  And it is in fact difficult to avoid, especially if you ever use arrays.  Because array indexing *is* pointer arithmetic + dereferencing.

Comment: A direct no no to pointer arithmetics is not a norm, but a well known fact in community I guess.

Comment: Given that array syntax is just another way of writing pointer arithmetics I don't see any reason to strictly avoid it. `&source[2]` exactly the same as `source+2`. And in this use case I find the latter even a bit more readable than using array syntax. BTW: You are invoking undefined behaviour be reading indetermined values of your pointer elements. And you forgot to cast to `void*` which is expected to be passed for `%p`.

Comment: Well this works but I don't like the cast:
memcpy((uint8_t *)buf_header + offset1 + offset2, val, val_size);

Comment: _Pointer arithmetics need to be avoided as much as you can_ is not a good hint for a C language learner.  If you don't understand pointer arithmetic, please don't confound people with your statements.  You have not realized that `int8_t *source[5]` IS NOT a pointer to an array, but an array of pointers (a very different object).

Comment: @JohnBollinger, array indexing is some _masked way_ of doing pointer arithmetic.  You are right, so don't blame me, I have also added a comment on this, so please read it before complaining.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a pointer to an array

```
    uint8_t *source[5];
```

Sorry, but this is not a pointer to an array.  It is an array of 5 pointers to `uint8_t`, uninitialized, so you should initialize it.

This is a pointer to an array:

```
    uint8_t (*source)[5];
```

(precedence of `[]` operator is higher than that of `*` in type expressions)

> ...what is going on here?

well, based on your wrong assumption, everything is expected to be incorrect.

```
    // Initial
    printf("%p\n", (void *)source); // 786796896

    // Offset by 2
    printf("%p\n", (void *)(source + 2)); // 786796912 (unexpected, more than 2)
```

`source + 2` is the address of the third array element of array `source` which is an array of pointers, so it's two pointer places offset from `source` itself (this is 16 bytes in 64bit architectures --the value you get--, and 8 bytes in 32bit architectures)

Just try with the declaration proposed, and you will get what you expect.

```
$ a.out
0x560bee9df060
0x560bee9df06a
$ _
```

(10 positions, as expected for two 5 `uint8_t` element arrays)

But you can check this yourself.

If you use the `sizeof` operator on `source` itself, you will get the size of an array (5 pointers, or 40 bytes, on 64bit arch) while as you state in your question, it should be the size of a single pointer (8 bytes, in 64bit arch)  If you declare it with the proposed declaration, then you will get 8 as it should be expetec, while if you do a `sizeof *source` (the size of the object pointed to by `source`), in this case you will get 5 (the size of an array of five `uint8_t` values) Try it and see it.

---

Final note about the alignment discussion handled in the comments to the question.

1. The declared object was an array of pointers, and not a pointer to an array of five `uint8_t`s, so its address (the value passed to `printf` it's indeed aligned and valid (it's indeed the address in the stack where the variable `source` has been created), and no U.B. is incurred on using that address, because the array contents are not used themselves, so it remains uninitialized and provokes no U.B.)
2. If declared correctly as an pointer to an array, its uninitialized value is printed ---the only unpredictable thing is the value itself---, but that doesn't require to dereference the pointer or alignment (which is not an issue, see next).  Pointer arithmetic, in this case should be avoided for uninitialized pointer variable, as it is not warranted that the destination value of the pointer can be a valid address, and so there's some, not harmful normally, U.B. (this is because the original uninitialized value can also be an invalid address itself, and should not cause a U.B. while just being uninitialized. The `(void *)` cast, by itself, normally doesn't cause any U.B.)
3. If declared as a pointer to an array, again, there's no alignment problem, as the base type of the pointer is an array of `uint8_t`s which has alignment of 1 (one) and so, any address should be acceptable.  As the pointer is not dereferenced, it behaves as any uninitialized variable, and so, it doesn't cause U.B.